# can't migrate postgres woth sequelize db:migrate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I can't migrate my models to PostgreSQL. i was r\trying with sequelize db:migrate but the output like:

```
Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.11.98:5432
```

how to resolve it?

Comment: Is your DB accessible by 192.168.11.98 and 5432 port from a computer where you're trying to run migrations? Did you try to access it by something like DBeaver?

Comment: Show `config.json` replacing a password with something